# jquery stop() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `DIV`s for products, and I have:

```
// mouseenter
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.productWrapper', function(){
    $(this).stop(true,true);
    $(this).find('.productWrapperContentVisible').animate({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: '1',   
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.productWrapperPrice').fadeIn();  
        $(this).find('.productWrapperByCompany').fadeIn();
    }); 
});

// mouseleave
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.productWrapper', function(){
    $(this).stop(true,true);
    $(this).find('.productWrapperPrice').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).find('.productWrapperByCompany').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).find('.productWrapperContentVisible').animate({
        height: '40px',
        opacity: '.8',      
    });
});
```

and there are about 20 of products in each page, while I'm using stop(true,true), after I move my mouse on many of them many times, this doesn't work right, they continue to change height, and sometimes `productWrapperPrice` is still there while I don't have my mouse over there, it should go hidden.. .

`sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gwsPB/`

What's wrong with my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// mouseenter
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.productWrapper', function () {
    $(this).find('.productWrapperContentVisible').stop(true, false).animate({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.productWrapperPrice, .productWrapperByCompany').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    });
}).on('mouseleave', '.productWrapper', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.productWrapperPrice, .productWrapperByCompany').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
    $this.find('.productWrapperContentVisible').stop(true, false).animate({
        height: '40px',
        opacity: '.8'
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gwsPB/1/)

The problem is: when you mouseenter and mouseleave immediately fast enough, your `animate` function in the mouseenter event ***is not finished yet***. When your call `$this.find('.productWrapperContentVisible').stop(true, true)`, the animation is stopped but the callback function is called which display them again

```
function () {
   $(this).find('.productWrapperPrice, .productWrapperByCompany')
          .stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}
```

By using `stop(true, false)`, the callbacks are not called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `stop()` on elements where are being animated, calling it on an ancestor element has no effect.

```
// mouseenter
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.productWrapper', function () {
    $(this).find('.productWrapperContentVisible').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.productWrapperPrice, .productWrapperByCompany').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    });
}).on('mouseleave', '.productWrapper', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.productWrapperPrice, .productWrapperByCompany').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
    $this.find('.productWrapperContentVisible').stop(true, true).animate({
        height: '40px',
        opacity: '.8'
    });
});
```

Comment: this solved the stopping other divs to animate at the same time, but still `productWrapperPrice` and `productWrapperByCompany` are visible sometimes while i leave the div...

Comment: @behz4d can you share a html sample